# How to make a jquery plugin use jquery.live?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am kinda in a bind. I got this color picker plugin that I am using and some text-boxes. So the color picker script runs and binds it too these text-boxes. But later on I dynamically load up more text-boxes and I want them to have the color picker plugin put on those text-boxes.

But currently it won't and I have no clue how to make them get this plugin. I tried "live" but that did not work too well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the $.live() can potentially slow things down, you might consider rebinding the function every time you create a new textbox.

```
$("#whateverDiv").append("<input type='text' class='specialTextbox' />";
$(".specialTextbox").colorPicker();

//some time later
$("#anotherDiv").append("<input type='text' class='specialTextbox' />";
$(".specialTextbox").colorPicker();
```

Comment: my understanding was you have something like this. You add the colorPicker script and let it run. Then the next script is your stuff and it then binds it all. Then thats it done and if you add another one it won't get rendered.

Comment: Simply call colorPicker() again after you add the next one

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').live('click', function() {
    functionInvocation( this );
});
```

That would attach a click event handler to any button elements added. You could adjust this to another type of action, but can you be more specific about what you need and how your color picker specifically works?

Answer (score 0):

How does the color picker script attach itself to the inputs in the first place?  With Thickbox, for example, it's simply a call to

```
tb_init('some-selector-here-to-which-thickboxes-should-be-applied');
```

Is there a corresponding call for this plugin that you could simply invoke yourself when you add the additional inputs later?

If not, it may require modification of the plugin to support that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the plugin itself by replacing bind with live within the function. Or add a parameter to use live rather than bind.

```
$(target).click(function(){
//plugin codes
});

//replace with this
$(target).live('click',function(){
//plugin codes
});
```